# Drawing points on QPixmap on QWidget (pyqt5)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwidget, paintevent

I have a QWidget with a QLayout on which there is a QLabel.
I set a QPixmap on the label. Wherever the user clicks on the image, I want to draw a point. I defined mouseReleaseEvent (which works) and paintEvent (but no points are drawn). I've read all similar questions and none of the solutions worked for me. Any help? My relevant code:

```
class ImageScroller(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, img):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self._image_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self._set_image(img)
        main_layout.addWidget(self._image_label)
        main_layout.addStretch()
        self.setLayout(main_layout)

    def _set_image(self, img):
        img = qimage2ndarray.array2qimage(img)
        qimg = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(img)
        self._img_pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(qimg)
        self._image_label.show()

    def paintEvent(self, paint_event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.begin(self)
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red))
        pen = QtGui.QPen()
        pen.setWidth(20)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.drawPoint(300,300)
        painter.drawLine(100, 100, 400, 400)
        for pos in self.chosen_points:
            painter.drawPoint(pos)
        painter.end()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, cursor_event):
        self.chosen_points.append(QtGui.QCursor().pos())
        self.update()
```

Comment: where is your `mouseReleaseEvent` implementation? have you called the `update()` method?

Comment: Yes I have. I edited the post with the mouseReleaseEvent implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `QtGui.QCursor.pos()` is getting the coordinates of the cursor with respect to the screen, but when you want to paint a widget you must be in the coordinates of the widget, for it the widget has the `mapToGlobal()` method:

```
self.mapFromGlobal(QtGui.QCursor.pos())
```

But in this case there is another solution, you must use the event that returns `mouseReleaseEvent` that has the information in the `pos()` method:

```
cursor_event.pos()
```

Another problem is that the label you created is above the widget so you do not see the points, the easiest thing is to draw the `QPixmap` directly with the `drawPixmap()` method.

Complete code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class ImageScroller(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        self.chosen_points = []
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self._image = QtGui.QPixmap("image.png")

    def paintEvent(self, paint_event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), self._image)
        pen = QtGui.QPen()
        pen.setWidth(20)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.drawPoint(300, 300)
        painter.drawLine(100, 100, 400, 400)
        for pos in self.chosen_points:
            painter.drawPoint(pos)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, cursor_event):
        self.chosen_points.append(cursor_event.pos())
        # self.chosen_points.append(self.mapFromGlobal(QtGui.QCursor.pos()))
        self.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = ImageScroller()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]